# Rewrite rule for URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

i want to write a rewrite rule for wordpress site

example

```
http://localhost/wordpress/test-test-test/
```

should be

```
http://localhost/wordpress/test/test/test/
```

convert - to /

is that possible or how to insert "test/test/test" to slug in word-press page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it straight through PHP with wordpress.

Here's a great article that shows the process:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/